# Grails submitToRemote always calls index method

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-mvc, gsp

I'm new to grails and not quiet understanding why my form keeps calling the index method of my controller even though I assign the action to call a test method.

Here is the gsp:

```
<g:form action="test">
        <g:submitToRemote update="updateMe" value="Click Me!" />
    </g:form>
    <div id="updateMe"></div>
```

Here is how it is rendered:

```
<form action="/CEFConnect/CEFTicker/test" method="post">
  <input onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:jQuery(this).parents('form:first').serialize(),
                 url:'/CEFConnect/CEFTicker/index',
                 success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#updateMe').html(data);},
                 error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});
                 return false" 
         type="button" value="Click Me!">
</form><div id="updateMe"></div>
```

The ajax is calling `'/CEFConnect/CEFTicker/index'` and not `'/CEFConnect/CEFTicker/test'`

Here is the controller:

```
class CEFTickerController {

def index() {
    render "<p>index called.</p>"
}

def list() {

} 

def test() {
    render "<p>test called.</p>"
}}
```

The page I'm calling this from is '/CEFConnect/CEFTicker/list'.  So, I'm not calling the action from the current action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `url` in `submitToRemote`

```
<g:submitToRemote url="[action: 'test']" update="updateMe" value="Click Me!"/>
```

Per [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html).